# Spark: Why the StructType merge method is private?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is a `merge` method in the [spark.sql.types package](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala#L391):

```
private[sql] def merge(that: StructType): StructType
```

Is there a particular reason it is private? I would like to use it in my project, is there any other way than copying the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know am very late but hope my answer might help someone else:

So, I found that ***StructType.merge()*** has not been included in spark version > 2.x

but Still you can use the ***StructType.merge()*** if you are using Spark with Java but in Scala it is not supported.

**Work around for Spark with Scala:**

```
val consolidatedSchema = test1Df.schema.++:(test2Df.schema).toSet
val uniqueConsolidatedSchemas = StructType(consolidatedSchema.toSeq)
```

**Spark with Java:**

```
StructType consolidatedSchema = test1Df.schema().merge(test2Df.schema());
```

If you want, you can check using Java and Scala with same version of Spark.